# How to open another activity with a pre-written EditText?

Tags: android

I have an activity which consists of an `EditText`. The problem is I want to open this activity with a pre-written `EditText`. 
Here is the example:
[image: Example of a pre-written EditText]

I want when I open this activity from the `MainActivity`, the text of EditText will always be set to "Tùng".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to transfer data from one activity to antoher. You should use `Intent`s:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourOtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("TUNG_ID", "Tung");
startActivity(intent);
```

And on the other activity. In `onCreate` method:

```
String tungString = getIntent().getStringExtra("TUNG_ID");
Log.d("ApplicationTag", tungString); //it's gonna print "Tung"

EditText et = findViewById(R.id.youredittext); //find your edittext to write text
et.setText(tungString); //This will populate received string into edittext
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `editText.setText("Text you want to show");` in your activity's `onCreate`/`onStart`/`onResume` method (depending on the expected behavior). Also make sure you first have a reference to your `editText` by calling `findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId)` before calling `setText` to this element.

Answer (score 0):

very very simple just put it in your XML

```
 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/edt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tùng"/>
```

or programattically you can set it oncreate of activity as below

```
edt.setText("Tùng");
```